App crash release build with obfuscated logs how I come to actual file line number
My App is working in Debug mode. When I generate Release build with minifyEnabled true it crashed. When I check in log it just showing at J2.c.l(SourceFile:46)
How I come to know what is J2?
In my knowledge there would some mapping file which tells about it but I don't know where it is.
I am using Android Studio Koala

It might be a bit late to answer. For anyone still stuck with this issue:
You are correct regarding the mapping file. Whenever you obfuscate your code a mapping file is also generated automatically. You can look for the same in your module's output directory
path: <module-name>/build/outputs/mapping/<build-type>/

The mapping file location remains the same across different Android Studio versions, including Koala.
